# "Command not found" after running a file compiled on the same directory

Tags: bash, files, gcc

I don't know what is going on...

```
d@d-SVF15A17CDB:~/University/CSC209/a1$ gcc -o remvocals remvocals.c
d@d-SVF15A17CDB:~/University/CSC209/a1$ dir
remvocals  remvocals.c
d@d-SVF15A17CDB:~/University/CSC209/a1$ remvocals
remvocals: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually run the file:

Make sure the file is executable (you can learn more about file permissions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)). If `gcc` succeeds in linking it should already be executable (thanks @steeldriver):

```
chmod +x remvocals
```

Execute the file:

```
./remvocals
```

Comment: Interesting, I remember the way I posted worked in another computer, why?

Comment: It can work if the folder you're working on is on the `PATH` environment variable. I don't think that's what you want though. To see what's on the `PATH` use: `echo $PATH`.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to `chmod +x` the file: it will be executable by default if `gcc` successfully links the binary.